# Services denied on changing userid for GMAIL API in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, gmail-api

**Error:**

> A first chance exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dl

I first tried by fetching emails, by using **"me"** string, but to make it available for other email addresses too, it is showing:

> delegations are not allowed.

Comment: You need to show the relevant code in your question. Create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: create new client id for the other address and place it in client_secret